# Can't pass random integer when calling makeText()

Tags: java, android, toast, android-toast

I am new to android and was playing around with the `makeText` method of `Toast` class. I noticed that when calling makeText, I could not pass an integer for the duration parameter other than `TOAST.LENGTH_LONG` and `TOAST.LENGTH_SHORT`. Android studio warned that it has been annotated with `@intDef` but when I opened the source code for Toast class, I couldn't find where the parameter was annotated. Any idea how this is enforced?

My target SDK version is `API 19: Android 4.4 (KitKat)`. The [signature](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/android/widget/Toast.java?av=f) is:

> public static Toast makeText(Context context, CharSequence text, int
>   duration)

Comment: What API version are you compiling against?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice : My target SDK version is API 19

Comment: `public static Toast makeText(Context context, CharSequence text, @Duration int duration)`

Comment: @k0sh for me it is: public static Toast makeText(Context context, CharSequence text, int duration)

Comment: Yes, and you wrote ```makeToast``` in the question @Kode

Comment: @NeilLocketz oops I corrected it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Android 5.1.1, the `duration` parameter of [`Toast.makeText()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/Toast.java#Toast.makeText%28android.content.Context%2Cjava.lang.CharSequence%2Cint%29) is annotated with [`@Duration`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/Toast.java#Toast.Duration). This annotation is in turn annotated with `@IntDef`.

Comment: But why can't I see it? And if the API 19 doesn't annotate it, why should I get the error? Sorry I am a bit confused. Can you please add some more explanation to the answer?

Answer (score 0):

below code is working for me

```
     final int SHORT_DELAY = 2000; // 2 seconds

  Toast.makeText(getActivity(),String.valueOf(12314),SHORT_DELAY).show();
```